# Fast algorithm to determine a negative number in a given array

Tags: algorithm

Please suggest if there is quicker way to find the negative number in a given array, provided that the array has only one negative number. I think sorting is an option, but it will be helpful if there is a quicker way.

Comment: Faster then `O(n)` when just traversing the array and checking for the one (!) negative number? Without any knowledge about the array (e.g. array us sorted) - no.

Comment: pretty sure you can just search the array.  That's O(n).

Comment: Sorting? What for? Just scan the array, you can't get below O(n).

Comment: Which language are you using? And what is the data type in the array? Is the array modelled with a contiguous memory block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting won't be quicker than going through all the elements of the array (because to sort you also have to do that).

The fastest possible thing to do is to go through the all array and stop once you detect one negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Just traverse the array. That is order ***n***. Sorting is at best order ***n(log n)***; at worst ***n<sup>2</sup>***.

Comment: "At worst" can be *much* worse than N^2 (though the really terrible options are mostly jokes, never intended for serious use).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin; yes I did consider that - I once saw an n^3 sort in production code.

Comment: Oh ouch -- Knuth gives an O(N^3) in TAOCP, but only as the shortest possible sorting code (in MIXAL).

Comment: Well, [Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) beats that on best, and on worst .. On best its O(n) on worst it's Unbounded. On average: O(n * n!).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest is to just scan the array until you find it.

If you're just doing this once, and don't need the array sorted for other purposes, it'll be faster to scan for the negative number than to do the sort. If, however, you need (or can use) the sorting for other purposes, or you may need to find the negative number several times, then sorting can end up saving time. Likewise, with some programs, spending extra time in preparation to get faster response when really crucial can be justified (but I've no idea whether that applies here or not).